# In Contact reports, why are the contacts' names not linked to their records?

Tags: contacts, civireport

Using CiviCRM 5.48.2 with WordPress (current version).

The other day I noticed that in my contact reports (e.g. Current Member List), the names are not linked to the person's record. The links are there in contribution reports, but not contact reports. This is the case both on the dashboard and in the reports area.

I have looked all over to see if this is some setting, but can't find anything.

Any suggestions welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: What report is Current Member List based on - there is no core report called that. Is it a report provided by an extension?

Comment: It is based on the Constituent Report (Summary) which I renamed and made copies of for other custom Contact reports.

Comment: And you're saying the contact name is not a link at all or is a link but not to the contact? In the core Constituent Report (Summary) it's a drilldown link to the Constituent Detail report.

Comment: Not a link at all. No links in these reports now. There used to be links. There are links in the Contribution reports, but not the Contact reports.

Comment: here is link to one of the demo sites (dmaster so running on latest) https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/report/instance/1?force=1&reset=1

Answer (score 1):

For some reports, the link is displayed if the contact id is included as a column for the report and in some, it is pointed to a report. Maybe try including contact id as a column!!

Comment: Tried that. Still no links.